# Firebase FCM notifications add action button

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, web-push

How to add action button to push notification like this:
[image]
I tried this and its not working:

=> https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/05/web-notifications-api-support-now.html

here's my notification payload:

```
array
(
    "title" =>  "FCM Message",
    "body" => "This is an FCM Message",
    "click_action" => "http://example.com/",
    "icon" => "/logo.jpg",
    "actions" => array(
        0 => array(
            'title' => 'Like',
            'click_action' => 'http://example.com/?aaa=1',
            'icon' => 'icons/heart.png',
        ),
        1 => array(
            'title' => 'Unsubscribe',
            'click_action' => 'http://example.com/?aaa=2',
            'icon' => 'icons/cross.png',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I tried with message payload also doesnt work:

```
$msg = array
(
    "webpush" =>  array
    (
        "notification" =>  array
        (
            "title" =>  "Fish Photos ",
            "body" =>  "Thanks for signing up for Fish Photos! You now will receive fun daily photos of fish!",
            "icon" =>  "firebase-logo.png",
            "image" =>  "guppies.jpg",
            "data" =>  array
            (
                "notificationType" =>  "fishPhoto",
                "photoId" =>  "123456",
            ),
            "click_action" =>  "https://example.com/fish_photos",
            "actions" =>  array(
                0 => array(
                    'title' => 'Like',
                    'action' => 'like',
                    'icon' => 'icons/heart.png',
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'title' => 'Unsubscribe',
                    'action' => 'unsubscribe',
                    'icon' => 'icons/cross.png',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android, you'll have to use RemoteInput and 'apply' action to the notification. Below is the summary and [here](https://medium.com/@info_67212/firebase-push-notification-with-action-button-in-flutter-a841da348097) are the details.

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_REPLY = "NotificationReply";

RemoveInput removeInput = new RemoteInput.Builder((Notification_REPLY))
    .setLabel("Approve Comments")
    .build();
```

Then create a PendingIntent for the reply action as below :

```
PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context:this,
    REQUEST_CODE_APPROVE,
    new Intent(packageContext:this,NotificationReciver.class)
        .putExtra(KEY_INTENT_APPROVE,REQUEST_CODE_APPROVE),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

Then attach the RemoteInput object to an action using addRemoteInput()

```
NotificationCompat.Action action =
    new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(ic_delete,
        title:"Approve", acceptPendingIntent)
        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
        .build();
```

Lastly, you'll have to apply the action to notification and display.

```
NotificationCompat.builder = notificaitonBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context:this,channelId:"channel_id")
    .addAction(action)
    // set rest of notification attributes e.g. title, auto cancel, icon etc.
```

You can pass the required information from the 'data' attribute of Firebase notification. You'll have to use onReceive() even to attach reply/buttons at the bottom of the message.

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) is another helpful link.

[image]

Comment: the question is for web push, not android

Comment: oh ! Thought it's for Android since the first image link points to Android and the question wasn't tagged to "web-push".

Answer (score 0):

Action buttons works with data payload while website is running in foreground. 
[tested on lcoalhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmnbZ.png)
Tried with below code working as expected.

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) { 
                                var notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
                                var notificationOptions = {
                                    body: payload.notification.body,
                                    data: payload.data,
                                    icon: payload.notification.icon,
                                    image: payload.data.Image,
                                    requireInteraction: payload.notification.requireInteraction,
                                    tag: payload.notification.tag,
                                    click_action: payload.data.click_action,
                                    requireInteraction: true,
                                    actions: [{
                                        action: "Test",
                                        title: "Test",
                                        icon: payload.data.action_button,
                                        height: "100px"
                                    }]
                                };
                                registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
                            },50)
                        });
```

add the above code in your javascript ie. `app.js`

I have sent payload from my server side - c# code.

```
            {              
                Image = "/image/img1.jpg",
                click_action = "https://secure.mdg.com/",
                action_button = "/image/button.jpg"                
            };

            var notificationModel = new NotificationEntityModel()
            {
                title = "Testing",
                body = "This is fcm push notification demo",
                Vibrate = new[] { 500, 110, 500, 110, 450, 110, 200, 110, 170, 40, 450, 110, 200, 110, 170, 40, 500 },
                icon = "/image/mdglogo.png",                       
                tag = "Test Notify"                
            };
```

Comment: This is working for Foreground, any idea for background notification? Buttons are not visible for background notification

Comment: This will work but it is hard coded of action button . I was trying to send different action button .