# Android overlay window notification in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

how to implement the android overlay window notification with some actions button to close the overlay window in xamarin android.

1. Push notifications will come from FCM but instead of showing android regular notifications I wanted to show the overlay notification message with my custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging service for push notifications doesn’t provide an option to add action buttons to the notification layouts. So in order to add the action button to notifications, the only way we have now is to create the notification in native and integrate it with Flutter.

For more, you can check:

https://medium.com/@info_67212/firebase-push-notification-with-action-button-in-flutter-a841da348097

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57917344/10308336